React Material UI VITE - Theme Problem - createTheme_default is not a function
in our React - Material UI Application for the frontend, we currently have the problem that sometimes when we switch the branch, we get the error: createTheme_default is not a function in the browser console log.
enter image description here
The chunk is the following:
// node_modules/@mui/material/Box/Box.js
init_identifier();

// node_modules/@mui/material/Box/boxClasses.js
init_generateUtilityClasses();
var boxClasses = generateUtilityClasses("MuiBox", ["root"]);
var boxClasses_default = boxClasses;

// node_modules/@mui/material/Box/Box.js
var defaultTheme = createTheme_default();
var Box = createBox({
  themeId: identifier_default,
  defaultTheme,
  defaultClassName: boxClasses_default.root,
  generateClassName: ClassNameGenerator_default.generate
});


The weird thing is, that there is nowhere displayed where this error happens.
I saw some posts online, but actually I couldn't find any fix related to this problem.
Our theme.ts looks like that:
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { ColorPartial } from "@mui/material/styles/createPalette";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Palette {
    blue: ColorPartial;
    red: ColorPartial;
    yellow: ColorPartial;
    teal: ColorPartial;
    neutral: ColorPartial;
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    blue: ColorPartial;
    red: ColorPartial;
    yellow: ColorPartial;
    teal: ColorPartial;
    neutral: ColorPartial;
  }
}

declare module "@mui/material/Button" {
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    blue: true;
    red: true;
    yellow: true;
    teal: true;
    neutral: true;
    cyan: true;
  }
}

declare module "@mui/material/TextField" {
  interface TextFieldPropsColorOverrides {
    blue: true;
    red: true;
    yellow: true;
    teal: true;
    neutral: true;
    cyan: true;
  }
}

declare module "@mui/material/ToggleButton" {
  interface ToggleButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    blue: true;
    red: true;
    yellow: true;
    teal: true;
    neutral: true;
    cyan: true;
  }
}

declare module "@mui/material/SvgIcon" {
  interface SvgIconPropsColorOverrides {
    blue: true;
    red: true;
    yellow: true;
    teal: true;
  }
}

const palette = {
  primary: {
    50: "#E0FCFF",
    100: "#BEF8FD",
    200: "#87EAF2",
    300: "#54D1DB",
    400: "#38BEC9",
    500: "#2CB1BC",
    600: "#14919B",
    700: "#0E7C86",
    800: "#0A6C74",
    900: "#044E54",
    main: "#2CB1BC",
  },
  neutral: {
    50: "#FAF9F7",
    100: "#E8E6E1",
    200: "#D3CEC4",
    300: "#B8B2A7",
    400: "#A39E93",
    500: "#857F72",
    600: "#625D52",
    700: "#504A40",
    800: "#423D33",
    900: "#27241D",
    main: "#857F72",
  },
  blue: {
    50: "#DCEEF8",
    100: "#B6E0FE",
    200: "#84C5F4",
    300: "#62B0E8",
    400: "#4098D7",
    500: "#2680C2",
    600: "#186FAF",
    700: "#0F609B",
    800: "#0A558C",
    900: "#003E6B",
    main: "#2680C2",
  },
  red: {
    50: "#FFEEEE",
    100: "#FACDCD",
    200: "#F29B9B",
    300: "#E66A6A",
    400: "#D64545",
    500: "#BA2525",
    600: "#A61B1B",
    700: "#911111",
    800: "#780A0A",
    900: "#610404",
    main: "#BA2525",
  },
  yellow: {
    50: "#FFFAEB",
    100: "#FCEFC7",
    200: "#F8E3A3",
    300: "#F9DA8B",
    400: "#F7D070",
    500: "#E9B949",
    600: "#C99A2E",
    700: "#A27C1A",
    800: "#7C5E10",
    900: "#513C06",
    main: "#E9B949",
  },
  teal: {
    50: "#EFFCF6",
    100: "#C6F7E2",
    200: "#8EEDC7",
    300: "#65D6AD",
    400: "#3EBD93",
    500: "#27AB83",
    600: "#199473",
    700: "#147D64",
    800: "#0C6B58",
    900: "#014D40",
    main: "#27AB83",
  },
  text: {
    primary: "#27241D",
    secondary: "#857F72",
  },
  background: {
    default: "#FAF9F7",
  },
};

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: palette,
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "Roboto, Arial, sans-serif",
  },
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          borderRadius: "5px",
        },
        contained: {
          backgroundColor: palette.primary[500],
          color: "#FFFFFF",
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: palette.primary[600],
          },
        },
        outlined: {
          color: palette.text.primary,
          border: `1px solid ${palette.neutral[200]}`,
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: palette.neutral[200],
          },
        },
        text: {
          color: palette.text.primary,
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: palette.neutral[100],
          },
        },
      },
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: "contained", color: "neutral" },
          style: {
            backgroundColor: palette.neutral[100],
            color: palette.text.primary,
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: palette.neutral[200],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: "contained", color: "yellow" },
          style: {
            backgroundColor: palette.yellow[500],
            color: "#FFF",
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: palette.yellow[600],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: "contained", color: "blue" },
          style: {
            backgroundColor: palette.blue[500],
            color: "#FFF",
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: palette.blue[600],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: "contained", color: "teal" },
          style: {
            backgroundColor: palette.teal[700],
            color: "#FFF",
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: palette.teal[800],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: "outlined", color: "yellow" },
          style: {
            borderColor: palette.yellow[500],
            color: palette.yellow[500],
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: palette.yellow[50],
              borderColor: palette.yellow[600],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: "outlined", color: "blue" },
          style: {
            borderColor: palette.blue[500],
            color: palette.blue[500],
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: palette.blue[50],
              borderColor: palette.blue[600],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: "outlined", color: "teal" },
          style: {
            borderColor: palette.teal[500],
            color: palette.teal[500],
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: palette.teal[50],
              borderColor: palette.teal[600],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: "outlined", color: "neutral" },
          style: {
            color: palette.text.primary,
            border: `1px solid ${palette.neutral[200]}`,
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: palette.neutral[100],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    MuiSvgIcon: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { color: "yellow" },
          style: {
            color: palette.yellow[500],
          },
        },
        {
          props: { color: "blue" },
          style: {
            color: palette.blue[500],
          },
        },
        {
          props: { color: "teal" },
          style: {
            color: palette.teal[500],
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    MuiTextField: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: "outlined" },
          style: {
            "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
              "& fieldset": {
                borderColor: palette.neutral[200],
              },
              "&:hover fieldset": {
                borderColor: palette.neutral[300],
              },
              "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
                borderColor: palette.neutral[500],
              },
            },
            "& .MuiInputLabel-root": {
              color: palette.neutral[400],
              "&.Mui-focused": {
                color: palette.neutral[700],
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
export default theme;


And it is used with the ThemeProvider.
Our main.tsx:
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.tsx";
import "./index.css";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import theme from "./theme";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


I can fix by doing the following:

rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules/.vite
npm cache clean --force
npm install


But then after creating a branch and maybe checking back to that branch - the error comes back.

I hope its not late because I have a similar case. Literally same case. I think what's happening is that vite is having some kind of issue when compiling the code that has a "Box" import in your code/React component. What I did to resolve it is just following this, some reddit discussion.
Just set your MUI Box component imports right after all the imports of Component from MUI package. Sample code below
import { useReducer } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

//* MUI

import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Chip from "@mui/material/Chip";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box"; //* Literally just add it here after all the imports of MUI packages in your code

//* Components
import TaskTableData from "@/components/ui/TaskTableData";
import FilterActions from "@/components/ui/FilterActions";

//* Types
import { FilterKeysAndValues, FilterInterface, StateTypes } from "./types";

//* Routes
import { paths } from "@/routes/MainRoute";

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [state, updateState] = useReducer(
    (prev: any, next: any): StateTypes => {
      return { ...prev, ...next };
    },
    {
      anchorEl: null,
      anchorElFilterPriority: null,
      anchorElFilterStatus: null,
      filters: {
        status: [],
        priority: [],
      },
      allFilters: [],
    }
  );

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const {
    anchorEl,
    anchorElFilterPriority,
    anchorElFilterStatus,
    filters,
    allFilters,
  } = state;
  //* Filter menu
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  //* Priority Filter menu
  const openPriorityFiler = Boolean(anchorElFilterPriority);

  //* Statue Filter menu
  const openStatusFilter = Boolean(anchorElFilterStatus);
  // console.log("filters:", filters);

  const removeFilterInList = (data: FilterKeysAndValues) => {
    const filterFiltersState = filters?.[
      data?.filterFrom as keyof FilterInterface
    ].filter((d: FilterKeysAndValues) => !d.keys.includes(data.keys));

    const newFilterAllFilters = allFilters.filter(
      (d: FilterKeysAndValues) => !d.keys.includes(data.keys)
    );

    updateState({
      filters: {
        ...filters,
        [data.filterFrom as keyof FilterInterface]: filterFiltersState,
      },
      allFilters: newFilterAllFilters,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* Filter Menu  */}

      {/* Filter controls  */}
      <Paper sx={{ p: 1 }}>
        <Box
          component="div"
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          <Box component="div" sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <FilterActions
              updateState={updateState}
              anchorEl={anchorEl}
              open={open}
              anchorElFilterPriority={anchorElFilterPriority}
              openPriorityFiler={openPriorityFiler}
              anchorElFilterStatus={anchorElFilterStatus}
              openStatusFilter={openStatusFilter}
              filterStatusList={filters?.status}
              filterPriorityList={filters?.priority}
              allFilterList={allFilters}
            />
            {(allFilters || []).map((d: FilterKeysAndValues, i: number) => (
              <Chip
                color={d.filterFrom === "priority" ? "primary" : "success"}
                key={i}
                label={d.values}
                variant="outlined"
                onDelete={() => removeFilterInList(d)}
              />
            ))}
          </Box>

          <Button
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            startIcon={<AddIcon />}
            onClick={() => navigate(paths.add_task)}
          >
            New task
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Paper>
      <br />
      {/* Table datas  */}
      <Paper elevation={3} sx={{ lineHeight: "60px", p: 2 }}>
        <TaskTableData />
      </Paper>
    </>
  );
}

I know this answer is weird but this solution resolves my similar problem.
